# Regex to support toll free numbers along with UAE numbers

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

I  have a regex that validates UAE numbers like: 00971585045336
here is the regex:
`/00971(?:50|51|52|53|54|55|56|57|58|59|2|3|4|6|7|9)\d{7}$/`

I have a requirement to add support for toll free numbers like:
**0097180038249953** or **0097180022988**

I am not good with regex so I need help to make it possible.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the format of toll free numbers in your country?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following regex, assuming the tool free number format is 00971800, followed by 5 or 8 digits. Your original regex is simplified with character classes. The test shows 4 valid numbers, followed by invalid numbers:

```js
const regex = /^00971((5\d|[234679])\d{7}|800(\d{5}|\d{8}))$/;
[
  '00971581234567',
  '0097171234567',
  '0097180012345',
  '0097180012345678',
  '0097158123456',
  '009715812345678',
  '009717123456',
  '00971712345678',
  '00971800123456',
  '009718001234567',
].forEach((str) => {
  let valid = regex.test(str);
  console.log(str + ' ==> ' + valid);
});
```

Output:

```
00971581234567 ==> true
0097171234567 ==> true
0097180012345 ==> true
0097180012345678 ==> true
0097158123456 ==> false
009715812345678 ==> false
009717123456 ==> false
00971712345678 ==> false
00971800123456 ==> false
009718001234567 ==> false
```

Explanation:

- `^` - start of string
- `00971` - expect literal text
- `(` - start group, used for logical OR

  - `(` - start group, used for logical OR

    - `5\d` - expect a `5`, followed by a digit
    - `|` - OR
    - `[234679]` - character class with a single char of allowed digits
  - `)` - end of group
  - `\d{7}` - 7 digits
  - `|` - OR
  - `800` - literal text
  - `(` - start group, used for logical OR

    - `\d{5}` - 5 digits
    - `|` - OR
    - `\d{8}` - 8 digits
  - `)` - end of group
- `)` - end of group
- `$` - end of string